# Problem with camera access on moverio BT 35E

Tags: android, epson-moverio

After following the documentation from Epson regarding camera access on the Moverio BT 35E, i just need to preview the camera output, but i cannot start my capture session.

Link to the docs: (https://tech.moverio.epson.com/en/bt-35e/developers_guide/developing_android_apps.html#ac2-3-2)

The problem seems to originate from the CameraDevice.startCapture() method. I have logged the output to my device, and the output is -1 (Failed)...

```
public void startCamera() {
    mCameraManager = new CameraManager(this);
    try {
        mCameraDevice = mCameraManager.open(mCaptureStateCallback, null, mSurfaceView.getHolder());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mCameraDevice.startCapture();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if(mCameraDevice != null) {
        mCameraDevice.startCapture();
        mTextView.setText(Integer.toString(mCameraDevice.startCapture()));
    } else {
        mTextView.setText("CameraDevice is Null");
    }
}
```

As far as i can tell, all i need to set up the camera manager, call the .open method with a statecallback method, and run the .startCapture method after this. This method fails, but i cannot seem to figure out why...

The documentation tells me nothing, except that an output of -1 means the method has failed, but does not tell me why.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! I had the wrong permissions set. Even though i only needed to retrieve the camera image, and display this, i needed to add permissions to save files, and record audio. My guess is that this is needed by default to start a capture session!

Added:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

to Manifest file